# Update Linux Kernel on a Codespace

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, codespaces, github-codespaces

## Problem

I'd like to use codespaces to work on a project that requires newer features of the Linux kernel (specifically the `accept()` syscall for `io_uring`). Even though I am using the [Ubuntu devcontainer](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/main/containers/ubuntu), this does not update the codespace's kernel to 5.11. I'm assuming that the host machine for Codespaces is using the 5.4.0 kernel.
Here's the output of `uname -sr`:

```
Linux 5.4.0-1070-azure
```

## Question

Is there any way to update the kernel to a newer version on the host Codespace machine?